# How to set associatedOwnerGroup with REST API in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, groups

Can you please let me know how to set **associatedOwnerGroup** with REST API to new site which does not have any group. 
I have created new group & able to **Add Role**. But I am not able to get any help related to set associatedOwnerGroup with REST API.

Comment: Check this link - AssociatedOwnerGroup for a web using REST api: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09288617-90d8-410a-88b2-30c3d77f0dc6/how-do-you-set-associatedownergroup-for-a-web-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Anyone have more help?  This link is not helpful:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09288617-90d8-410a-88b2-30c3d77f0dc6/how-do-you-set-associatedownergroup-for-a-web-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment